# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#coding:utf-8
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://news.qq.com/'
wbdata = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(wbdata,'lxml')
news_title = soup.select("div.text > em.f14 > a.linkto")

for n in news_title:
    title = n.get_text()
    link = n.get("href")
    data = {"标题":title,"链接":link}
    print(data)
    f = open('news.txt','wb')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

[image]

Here are codes.
So when I run it,it gives"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'",I tried many solutions,no help.
Can someone help me?
thx!

Comment: Please edit your question with the entire error message. It includes information about the line which causes the error.

Comment: Also please describe the desired result of your program.

Comment: File "E:\重要文件\1140556027\FileRecv\python爬取图片\腾讯新闻\爬取腾讯新闻.py", line 16, in <module>
    f.write(data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
[Finished in 1.2s with exit code 1]

Comment: Please edit your question rather than paying a comment. Also tell us which line is 16?

Comment: you can try `f.write(str(data))`

Comment: i tried f.write(str(data)).but failed

Comment: What about f.write(bytes(str(data)), 'utf8')? I had a similar issue with wfile.write on http.server and had to convert my dict object first into str, then bytes with encoding. (Probably a little late for OP but for anyone else who might stumble upon the same error!)

Comment: @Prajwal no, **don't** just dump the string representation to a file and call it serialization. use a built-in serialization format like JSON

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga totally agree. Thought he might just be trying to write just title from the page. If it is an object, then he needs a proper serialiser and de-serialiser.

Answer (score 2):

f.write(data)

This is where the problem is. 
You are passing in a dictionary instead of a byte like object.
For example when I change your code to the following:

```
#coding:utf-8
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://news.qq.com/'
wbdata = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(wbdata,'lxml')
news_title = soup.select("div.text > em.f14 > a.linkto")

for n in news_title:
    title = n.get_text()
    link = n.get("href")
    data = {"k":title,"a":link}
    print(data)
    f = open('news.txt','wb')
    data = b'123'
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

... I get the following:

```
{'k': '辽宁舰将绕台一周“武吓”蔡英文？外交部回应', 'a': 'http://news.qq.com/a/20170104/031454.htm'} ...
```

Which I assume is what you want.

Alternatively change the line:

```
f = open('news.txt', 'wb')
```

to

```
f = open('news.txt', 'w')
```

and that way you can write in str rather than a byte-like object.
In any case you shouldn't be passing in a dict.

Comment: Can u tell why,"data = b'123'"mean what?why?

Comment: Its just any byte string.
f.write() expects a byte-like object.
I just put that in there to prevent your code from halting with that error.

Comment: When I use your way, I can't write the result into the news.txt.In the file,it shows"123",why's that?

Comment: Ahh... the code example I gave above was simply to highlight that you cannot directly put in a dictionary into the f.write() function. 
It either expects as input a byte string/byte-like object if you use f = open('news.txt', 'wb') or expects as input a normal python string if you use f = open('news.txt', 'w').

The reason why the .txt file shows "123" is because I am inputting in b'123', which is a byte string containing 123. 

So you either need to convert your key and value strings into byte strings or normal python strings before you write them to the file.

Comment: thank you vary much. please tell me how to write 'data' into the file.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should  open the file before write the title and the link,when you write end close the file .

```
f = open('news.txt','wb')
for n in news_titles:
    title = n.get_text()
    link = n.get("href")
    data= {
        '标题':title,
        '链接':link
    }
    f.write(data['标题'])
    f.write(':')
    f.write(data['链接'])
    f.write('\r\n')
f.close()
```